# Product Pi Notation

Tags: products, pi

I wonder what is the properties of Product Pi Notation? I can't found anywhere about the properties.

First of all, i have:

$X=\beta\alpha\\
X^2=\beta^2\alpha(\alpha + 1) \\
X^3=\beta^3\alpha(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2) \\
. \\
. \\
. \\
\text{And so forth.}
$

My question is. I want to write this form into Pi Notation (If it's possible):

We know that the pattern for $X^n$ is the following:

$X^n=\beta^n\alpha(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2)\cdots (\alpha+(n-1))$

And with the Product Pi, is the following true?

$X^n=\beta^{n}\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\alpha + k\right)\quad,n=1, 2, 3,\ldots$

If it's wrong, please to tell me what is the right one? Please help, Thanks.^

Comment: I think it's correct

Comment: Actually it's an exponent. Cz i found the pattern for Expectation value for Gamma Distribution, and i want to make the formula simpler. ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the definition is
$$
\prod_{a\leq k \leq b} f(k) = f(a) f(a+1) \cdots f(b),
$$
with the empty product (which occurs e.g., if $b<a$) being defined as $1$ (the multiplicative identity).

Answer (score 0):

The formula  $\beta^n \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(\alpha+k) $ does generate the right hand sides of those equations.

I hope the superscript on the left refers to indices and not power.

Comment: Remark: you do not want to omit the expectation notation.